# Application of Schwarz Lemma Gamelin IX problem 2

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem in Gamelin's Complex Analysis.

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z| <1$ . Show that if $f(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$, then $|z_0|^m \geq f(0)$. Hint: Let $\phi(z) = \frac{(z-z_0)}{1-\overline{z_0}z}$ which is a ractional linera transformation mapping the unit disk onto itself and show that $|f(z)|\leq |\phi(z)|^m$.

I tried following the hint, but I am having a hard time showing that $|f(z)|\leq |\phi(z)|^m$. We know that since $f(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$, then $f(z) = (z-z_0)^mg(z)$ for some function $g(z)$ that is analytic at $z_0$ and $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Thus, I think if I show that $|g(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|1-\overline{z_0}z|}$, then I would be done but I don't know how to show this. Does anyone have any suggestion or hint on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints: let $g(z)=f(\phi ^{1} (z))$. Use the fact that $\phi $ maps the open disk onto itself (and the unit circle onto itself) and is bi-holomorphic. Show that $\frac {g(z)} {z^{m-1}}$ is analytic and it vanishes at $0$. Apply Schwarz Lemma to this function.